# Firebase realtime database - Wildcard rules

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I'm a bit confused about firebase rules. This is my realtime database. Each node inside "1" is created using the firebase unique id of the user. And in the user's node there is a list of objects.

The objective is for the user to be able to create this node if it doesn't exist, and allow the user to read/write only inside this node.

[image]

I tried this but it doesn't work. I get permission error.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "1": {
      "$key": {
        ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $key",
        ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $key"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note: In the future there will be other parent nodes ("2","3" etc) So it is important to keep the "1". Also in case it matters I am using firebase anonymous sign in.

I appreciate the help.

**UPDATE:**

I retrieve the installationId like this:

```
Task<String> getIdTask = FirebaseInstallations.getInstance().getId()
```

and access the database like this:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference()
                .child("1")
                .child(installationId)
```

Trying to access the database using above code gives this:

```
Listen at /1/cKYZwWrlRmSof79rtfuX82 failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied
```

---

**SOLUTION:**
I just realized the magnitude of my mistake. To retrieve the userId I was using

```
FirebaseInstallations.getInstance().getId()
```

instead of this which is what firebase sees as userId:

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
```

Using the later one solved the issue.

Comment: Rules on their own don't do anything yet. Can you show the minimal **code** that produces the error, and in there show that your code satisfies the conditions of your rules by logging the UID of the current user.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanx for replying. I updated the post to include my code and the error log

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Nevermind I just realized what I was doing wrong. The rules were fine I was just using the wrong key in my code. Which I realized when I copied the code here in the post so thank you for making me do that :P

Comment: Good to hear you found the problem!     I voted to close the question as a typo/ephemeral issue.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you'd add another node, that actually links the UID with your user ID, how shall it know about it? I'd suggest to reconsider the structure and get rid of that superfluous node altogether; just use the UID. It's not that it wouldn't be possible, to lookup values by UID ... but it might be an unfortunate database design, which ignores the given environment.

Comment: You mean have the nodes that represent the users be  parent nodes in the database? In this case the rules I posted would work?

Comment: It's commonly easier to accept the fact the Firebase uses UID instead of integer ID... and when the node has the name of the UID, it's easier to write rules - as anything else would require lookups within the condition (which also slightly slows down the request, it's about milliseconds, but when it's about processing that can be avoided, I'd go for it).